# SKSpriteNodes bounce off of each other when they should check if touching

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I want my code to be able to check when two SKSpriteNodes (`purplePentagon` and `purpleGoal` ) are touching, however, sometimes if the node is going fast enough it'll just bounce off it like it would any other node.

This is the code I have in the update() function in GameScene.swift

```
if(purplePentagon?.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies().contains((purpleGoal?.physicsBody)!))! {
    purplePentagon?.isHidden = true
    purplePentagon?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    purpleScored = true
}
```

It works well if the `purplePentagon` isn't going that fast but if it is going fast it'll just bounce off.

Comment: You really should include much more code for this kind of question, for example the how the objects physicsBodies are setup what their collisionBitMasks are and what their contactBitMasks are

Comment: It sounds like you are not defining contactTestBitMask and collisionBitMask correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you checking the physics contacts in update? vs using the built in physics function

`func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)` ?

you probably have the collision bit mask set to each other as well as the contact bit mask

```
self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.goal
self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.obstacle
```

if you don't want them to bounce off each other make sure that the `collisionBitMask` property of the physicsBody doesn't contain the other object. But keep the `contactTestBitMask` set to each other so that you can detect when they collide.

> edit for multiple instances

```
self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.goal1 | PhysicsCategory.goal2 | PhysicsCategory.goal3
```

Comment: if this fixes your issue please make sure to mark this as the correct answer so that others can benefit from your question

Comment: Hi Sorry that it's been a while but I have an issue with setting the categoryBitMask and collisionBitMask that I hadn't realized earlier... In my game I have up to for SKSpriteNodes on the scene at one time, and each of them have a node that is their goal. Each node should be able to collide with everything BUT their goal, but since the collisionBitMask is just an integer I'm completely unsure how to do this. Thanks.